# Track reference to a backbone view object with chrome Heap Profiler

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

I've read a lot about how to use Crome dev tool to chase memory leaks. But I am not able to track what keeps my view from being GC. I see a detached DOM element and when I expand it, I can see that it is referenced by `document in Window / localhost:3000/registration @1129109`. Is it possible to see the problem from the screenshot? I've checked everything to make sure that all views are closed and no events and other reference to views are left behind but of no avail.

The code structure in short:
`app` - is an object literal
`overlay` - backbone view
`dialog` - backbone view.

```
app.overlay = new Overlay();
app.overlay.registerComponent({view: new DialogView()})
app.overlay.show();
```

When user closes the dialog, there is a `close()` called on `dialogView`, then `app.overlay.close()` and `app.overlay = null;`

I should have all views closed and detached form the DOM but I can see DOM elements from dialog's template. I use Browserify.

[image]